# How to get the AWS environment in rails app for conditional functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

In my rails app, I want to differentiate from two AWS environments: sandbox and production.

How do I check and confirm what AWS environment the app is in to apply different functionality between the environments?

Is it possible to use something like `ENV['AWS_ENV'] == 'sandbox'`?

The devops team uses Jenkins to launch.

Comment: Common way to do this, you must split your config for different environments with gem 'config'

Comment: @Alex808 using a gem that replicates core functionality that is built into rails is bad advice. I hope your not actually doing this.

Comment: core functionality doesn't have such short and elegant way to do this, for commercial project devops usually use .json and .yaml config file rather than .rb

Comment: If you need just sandbox flag to control your flow above you standard environment you can add in your /environments/ENV.rb file config.sandbox = ENV["sandbox"].present? and check it in application by if Rails.application.config.sendbox or define global in initializers SANDBOX = ENV["sandbox"].present?

Comment: Depends on what your definition of elegant is. There are plenty of "commercial projects" that realize that ruby is not Java  and that you don't need YML or JSON configuration which is just an additional layer of indirection.

Comment: of course you can always use ENV variables without any config files at all, IMHO: approach of configuration depends on your devops or company deploy pipeline rules

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you can create any number of additional environments. A Rails environment is in its core nothing more than a string passed through the `RAILS_ENV` environmental variable which causes rails to load a separate set of config files.

Given `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'sandbox'`:

- `Rails.env` will return `sandbox` and `Rails.env.sandbox?` will be true.
- Rails will load `/config/environments/sandbox.rb`
- It will use the `sandbox` key in `database.yml` if you are using ActiveRecord
- It will use the `sandbox` key in `secrets.yml`
- It will use the `sandbox` [encrypted secrets in Rails 6](https://medium.com/@kirill_shevch/encrypted-secrets-credentials-in-rails-6-rails-5-1-5-2-f470accd62fc).

What you are setting up sounds a lot like an staging environment in which case you can start off with just:

```
git cp config/production.rb config/staging.rb
```

And then set `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` on the AWS environment to `staging`.

Comment: And no you don't need the `config` gem.

Comment: just want to confirm that by set `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` to `staging`, you can `export RAILS_ENV=staging` in the environment variables.

Comment: Yes, ENV in ruby is a hash containing env vars of the system. I haven't actually configured AWS so I cant say that will actually set an env var.